# Why does my app crash when UISearchBar's textDidChange is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, crash, uisearchbar

I have a UITableView which shows all of the songs in the Music Library, which works fine. However, when I start typing in the search bar to narrow down the search results, the app crashes immediately. Like as soon as I press one letter on the keyboard, it crashes. I've tried reworking my `textDidChange:` method but it always crashes, no matter what. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, could anyone help? Thanks.

Header:

```
@interface PTTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate>
@property (strong,nonatomic)UITableView* tableView;
@property (strong,nonatomic)UISearchBar* searchBar;
@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "PTTableViewController.h"

@implementation PTTableViewController

MPMediaQuery *songsQuery;
NSArray *songsArray;
NSMutableArray *filteredArray;
NSMutableArray *songTitlesArray;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 75,150) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
    
    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
    
    songsQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    songsArray = [songsQuery items];
    
    songTitlesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (MPMediaItem *item in songsArray) {
        [songTitlesArray addObject:[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]];
    }
    filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    filteredArray = [songTitlesArray copy];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return filteredArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    NSLog(@"search changed");
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(helper) withObject:nil];

}

-(void)helper{
    [filteredArray removeAllObjects];
    
    if ([self.searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        filteredArray = [songTitlesArray copy];
    } else {
        for (NSString *object in songTitlesArray){
            if ([object rangeOfString:self.searchBar.text].location == NSNotFound){
                NSLog(@"string not found");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"string found");
                [filteredArray addObject:object];
            }
        }
    } [self.tableView reloadData];
}
@end
```

Comment: That's because you are removing all elements from filteredArray without updating the table view?

Comment: What is the crash message?

Comment: I’m actually running this code in SpringBoard on a jailbroken device, so when the “app” crashes, I mean the device resprings / soft reboot? Strangely, there is no crash report produced.

Comment: you are calling the helper in background so also `[self.tableView reloadData]` is called in background. How should the main thread with the UI holding the filteredArray handle this? First thing to try, wrapping the reloadData in a GCD block and addressing the main thread for the reload instead. Because it is possible to have a table with no entries, thats not a bug, it's a feature but still pointless when your threads are messed up.

Comment: It still crashes on the main thread. The reason I made it run in the background is because the keyboard will also lag if called on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

First...

You're getting a crash because you do this:

```
filteredArray = [songTitlesArray copy];
```

Which assigns a **non-mutable** copy of `songTitlesArray` to `filteredArray`.

When you then try to do this:

```
[filteredArray removeAllObjects];
```

you're trying to mutate a non-mutable object.

You can fix this (first) problem in a couple ways...

One way is to change all instances of `copy` to `mutableCopy`:

```
filteredArray = [songTitlesArray mutableCopy];
```

However, using your exact code, you'll introduce new crashes because you'll be executing UI actions on a background thread.

Next... Are you *sure* you're getting "keyboard lag"?

You may want to change a few things:

- make `_filteredArray` non-mutable
- instead of calling `removeAllObjects` simply re-create the array
- use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` instead of looping through and comparing each string

Give this a try - because I don't have your `MPMediaQuery` I'll generate 500 strings as "song titles":

```
@interface PTTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate>
@property (strong,nonatomic)UITableView* tableView;
@property (strong,nonatomic)UISearchBar* searchBar;
@end

@implementation PTTableViewController

//MPMediaQuery *songsQuery;
NSArray *songsArray;
NSArray *filteredArray;
NSMutableArray *songTitlesArray;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 75,150) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
    
    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
    
    //  songsQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    //  songsArray = [songsQuery items];
    //
    //  songTitlesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //  for (MPMediaItem *item in songsArray) {
    //      [songTitlesArray addObject:[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]];
    //  }
    //  filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //  filteredArray = [songTitlesArray copy];

    // I don't have your Query, so let's create a 500 element string array,
    //  using the row number + one of the following words in each entry

    NSString *samples = @"These are some random words for the song titles.";

    // So, we'll have:

    //  "Row: 0 These"
    //  "Row: 1 are"
    //  "Row: 2 some"
    //  "Row: 3 random"
    //  "Row: 4 words"
    //  "Row: 5 for"
    //  "Row: 6 the"
    //  "Row: 7 song"
    //  "Row: 8 titles."
    //  "Row: 9 These"
    //  "Row: 10 are"
    //  "Row: 11 some"
    //  "Row: 12 random"
    //  "Row: 13 words"
    //  "Row: 14 for"
    //  ... etc
    
    NSArray *a = [samples componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    
    songTitlesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        NSString *w = a[i % [a count]];
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row: %d %@", i, w];
        [songTitlesArray addObject:s];
    }
    
    filteredArray = [songTitlesArray copy];
    
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return filteredArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    
    cell.textLabel.text = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    return cell;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    [self helper];
}

-(void)helper{
    if ([self.searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        filteredArray = [songTitlesArray copy];
    } else {
        NSString *w = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] '%@'", self.searchBar.text];
        NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:w];
        filteredArray = [songTitlesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
@end
```

As a side note, you've done a nice job of demonstrating one of the (many) reasons **NOT** to try and develop on a ***jailbroken device***.

Comment: Thanks, changing "copy" to "mutableCopy" fixed the crashes!